# Check the Lock on an object in java

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, sleep, synchronized

I want to check the lock on an object of the class. I use `Thread.holdsLock(this)` for this. Is this the Right way?

My question is how I can check if the object is locked for the main method and also check the lock on static methods.

```
public class CheckLock {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        objectLockClass olc=    new objectLockClass();
        Thread t1=new Thread(olc);
        t1.start();
    }
}

class objectLockClass implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        boolean isLocked = true;
        int counter=0;     
        synchronized (this) {
            while (isLocked) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("lock object in run  : " + Thread.holdsLock(this));
                if (counter==5 ) isLocked=false;
                    counter++;
            }
        }
```

The output is:

```
lock object in run  : true
lock object in run  : true
lock object in run  : true
lock object in run  : true
lock object in run  : true
lock object in run  : true
```

Comment: For a normal lock, yes. I agree with this way of doing this.

Comment: @JosefE. can i check the lock on object in main method by using t1 with olc instance.

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking. Please clarify.

Comment: You can't get a reference to the thread that has the lock without native code.

Comment: However, for more control over your thread you should look into concurrency.

Comment: @JBNizet i want to  check with holdsLock() that object is locked or the class is locked. also that please make it clear if thread lock the instance of object then other threads cannot access that instance and in case of static method weather it locks the whole class.

Comment: A synchronized block never locks a class or an object. It only prevents another thread from entering a code block that is synchronized on the same lock. Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

Comment: @JBNizet  Okey, was confused for lock on object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how I can check the object is locked for main method and also check lock on static methods?

An object isn't locked *for a method*.  It's just locked.  period.  The utility of Java's `synchronized` keyword is that no two threads will ever be allowed to synchronize on the same object at the same time.

---

It doesn't usually make sense to ask whether some other thread has an object locked.  The `Thread.holdsLock(foo)` method won't tell you that:  It only tells whether the *calling* thread has foo locked.  Suppose there *was* a method, `Thread.otherThreadHoldsLock(foo)`, and suppose you called it like this:

```
Object foo = ...;

if (Thread.otherThreadHasLocked(foo)) {
    doSomething();
} else {
    doSomethingElse();
}
```

It doesn't give you any useful information:  This code could call doSomething() with foo locked, or with foo not locked; and it could call doSomethingElse() with foo locked, or with foo not locked.  There's no guarantee, because another thread could acquire the lock or release the lock at any time.